# Alter certain bytes in many files

Tags: bash, shell-script, files, binary

I need a large number of damaged `.png` files in order to test my project. To that end, I need to set all bytes from the 0x054-th to the  0xa00-th to 0.

<sub>[`.png`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Network_Graphics) files contain chunks with checksums, I want to alter the image data chunk (IDAT), without updating the checksum. Furthermore, I want to damage a lot of bytes, so that a visible (black) area appears when displaying the image (provided the viewing program ignores the checksum mismatch).</sub>

Here is what I have got so far:

```
#!/bin/sh

# This script reads all .png or .PNG files in the current folder,
# sets all bytes at offsets [0x054, 0xa00] to 0
# and overwrites the files back.

temp_file_ascii=outfile.txt
temp_file_bin=outfile.png
target_dir=.
start_bytes=0x054
stop_bytes=0xa00
len_bytes=$stop_bytes-$start_bytes

for file in $(find "$target_dir" -name "*.png")         #TODO: -name "*.PNG")
do
    # Copy first part of the file unchanged.
    xxd -p -s $start_bytes "$file" > $temp_file_ascii

    # Create some zero bytes, followed by 'a',
    # because I don't know how to add just zeroes.
    echo "$len_bytes: 41" | xxd -r >> $temp_file_ascii

    # Copy the rest of the input file.
    # ??

    mv outfile.png "$file"
done
```

---

EDIT: the finished script, using the accepted answer:

```
#!/bin/sh

if [ "$#" != 3 ]
then
    echo "Usage: "
    echo "break_png.sh <target_dir> <start_offset> <num_zeroed_bytes>"
    exit
fi

for file in $(find "$1" -name "*.png")
do
    dd if=/dev/zero of=$file bs=1 seek=$(($2)) count=$(($3)) conv=notrunc
done
```

Comment: Note that `xxd -p -s 0x54` would start at the 0x55th byte (`xxd -p -s 0` starts at the first byte), not 0x54th. You may want to clarify your question to state which one you want.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas, I didn't know that. I need the first modified byte to be 0x54-th and the last to be (0xa00-0x001)-th.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do something much simpler with `dd`:

```
dd if=/dev/zero \
   of="$your_target_file" \
   bs=1 \
   seek="$((start_offset))" \
   count="$((num_zeros))" \
   conv=notrunc
```

With `$start_offset` being the start of your range of bytes to zero out (zero-based, as in to erase from the n<sup>th</sup> byte, use n-1), and `$num_zeros` the length of that range. The `$((...))` will take care of converting hexadecimal to decimal.

(Other tests you could run would be to set `if` to `/dev/urandom` rather than `/dev/zero`, or overwrite the checksums with random data too.)

Comment: Note that `0x54` makes `$start_offset=84` and ending `0xa00` makes `$num_zeros=2476`.

Comment: @RalphRönnquist, if that's meant to be _from the 0x054-th to the 0xa00-th_, then start_offset would be 83 (0x54 -  1) and num_zeros would be 2477 (0xa00 - 0x54 + 1).

Comment: Thanks, I was sure someone would come out with a one liner for the task I have been trying to solve for an hour. AND I learned about $((...)).

Answer (score 2):

With `ksh93`:

```
 PATH=/opt/ast/bin:$PATH find "$targetdir" -name '*.png' -type f -exec ksh93 -c '
   for file do
      head -c "$((0xa00 - 0x54 + 1))" < /dev/zero 1<> "$file" >#((0x54 - 1))
   done' ksh {} +
```

`>#((...))` being the seek operator in `ksh93`. That's relatively efficient in that it runs as few ksh93 as possible and all the commands are built-in.

With recent versions of `zsh`:

```
find "$targetdir" -name '*.png' -type f -exec zsh -c '
  zmodload zsh/system
  z=${(pl:0xa00-0x54+1::\0:)}
  for file do
    {sysseek -u1 0x54-1 && print -rn $z} 1<> $file
  done' zsh {} +
```

Those change the 0x54th to 0xa00th bytes (2477 bytes). It seems like you actually want to change the 0x55th to 0xa00th ones though. If that's the case, just remove the `+ 1`s and `- 1`s in the codes above.